# How to insert after the last element of a resized std::vector?

Tags: c++, vector, std, push-back

I know how much space I initially need in a `std::vector`. So I use `.resize()` to set the new vector to that size. But when using `.push_back()` afterwards, it adds the elements at the end of the allocated size increasing it by one.

How can I add new elements automatically in the empty placed of a resized vector?

Comment: Use `reserve` instead of `resize`. Then you can `push_back` as normal but you won't incur any memory reallocations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How can I add new elements automatically in the empty placed of a resized vector?

That is what you are doing. `resize` fills the new space with value-initialized elements, so there are no "empty places". It seems like you need to call `std::vector::reserve` instead.

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4}; // size = 4
v.reserve(100); // size = 4, capacity = 100
v.push_back(5); // no re-allocations. size  5.
```

Answer (score 3):

By using the method `reserve` instead of `resize`, your `push_back` will do the job without reallocating memory.